# My boss is asking me to provide her with personal technical support that has nothing to do with the business. What do I say to her?

Tags: management, skills, job-description

I work part-time at an independent bookstore with two storefronts in the same town as the publicity and events manager. The storefront where I work is often quite distracting, but I do my best to do the job while also being the cash wrap/gift wrap/shipment person.

I left my previous job doing tech support because I don't enjoy the high pressure, immediate fix nature of it, but I do enjoy teaching people new things (to those who *want* to learn).

As the current publicity manager, I'm responsible for a lot of technical/editorial things (website design, advertisement design, writing press releases) that my co-workers can't or don't want to do.

When my boss asks me to do personal, technical things for her, I feel like she's exploiting me. They don't have to do with the business (e.g filling out forms so she can attend a political convention), and when I've tried to explain to her "how" to do things, she's said she either doesn't understand or wasn't listening. She was supposedly excited to hire me because of my technical background, but she won't give me the time or environment necessary to do business-related technical things, like updating the website.

I was paid +$3/hr more in my last job doing technical stuff; **is it right to ask for more money** if my boss wants me to do personal, technical support, or **would I be better off just asking for a raise in general, and the chance to do my best work in a different, less distracting environment?** She doesn't seem to think it's worth a full-time job (or changing storefronts/days when I work to avoid all the distractions), but I might be amenable to doing publicity as an independent contractor, but I don't know if she would see that as beneficial.

Comment: So get another employer? I don't get your question, it is uninteresting work that you don't enjoy, ok. Have you talked to her about that? Can you not leave for some reason (i.e. you know her/friend, personal investment, etc.)? I would say to start applying for bigger opportunities or corporate positions as those could expand your skills (which this position is obviously not doing). PS - I did NOT down vote this. Though it needs to be redefined/clarified.

Comment: Don't flatter yourself entry level support is very cheap.

Comment: Right now it is kind of unclear what you want. Do you want to avoid doing any tech support? Do you want to limit it to a reasonable (to you) amount? Do you want more money? More respect from your boss? Please clarify what your goal is.

Comment: @ИвоНедев define "very cheap," please. Especially for someone (my boss) who is so technologically illiterate that she can't even search Google if I'm not there.

Comment: @Azurite What i meant is friends of mine, doing full time tech support are doing minimum wage.

Comment: @B1313 I've tried to get her to realize that publicity takes concentration and time and should be full-time, and not involve managing a store. I've tried to get her to realize that me going part-time was both for my grad school and so I could focus primarily on publicity, but she won't pay me for work I do when I'm not at the store, so I don't do work off-site, even though it would help with the load when I am there. I do enjoy the publicity part of the job, just not the other parts. Tech support in particular has nothing to do with the job she hired me for.

Comment: @sleske ultimately my goal would be to get paid more for the highly technical stuff she has me doing that takes away from my time working on publicity. I don't mind helping her from time to time, since it's usually easy or rare, but she is asking for personal stuff when I don't have the time for the tasks she hired me for.

Answer (score 5):

That would depend on whether or not you want to keep your job and relationship with your boss. Bosses asking for little things or even coworkers asking is not unusual at all. You have a useful skillset.

If you don't want to do it you can basically either feign ignorance or kick up a fuss. Or get a job elsewhere where they don't know you have these skills.

My strategy is just to feign ignorance "I have no idea on those gadgets, I just do computers, sorry.". But this is best done the first time rather than later on.

It also depends on your seniority, juniors are pretty much expected to do whatever they're told to do within reason.

Comment: "My strategy is just to feign ignorance" . . . pretty much a requirement for any technical person surrounded by non-technical people in today's world.

Comment: Unfortunately it's way too late for that, especially given she was so excited to hire someone who used to work for a well-known tech company. I've only heard that second-hand, though.

Answer (score -1):

Is your boss the owner of the company? If she's not the owner, then by making you do work that is paid for by the company's owner, but only serves her, she is stealing from the company's owner.

If she is the sole owner, then having the company pay for your work will reduce profit and therefore tax liability, so she is stealing company taxes from the tax office. Also, to be able to pay for your work the company would have had to pay her salary or dividends, on which she would have had to pay tax.

Comment: Valid and valuable information.  Do you have any recommendations on actions that can be taken in this scenario?

Comment: So report her to the IRS for tax evasion?

Comment: "... *so she is stealing company taxes from the tax office*." Sorry, but that's ridiculous. Are you saying corporations have a legal obligation to maximize their tax liability?

Comment: @Resigned: I see no evidence of anything not being reported properly and accurately.

Comment: @Resigned: Under what law? What jurisdiction are you assuming? Does the boss use her iPhone in the course of her job duties?

Comment: While this is true, it is not really a concern for the employee. That's up to the owners (if there are any others) and the tax office to judge. Plus, if she uses her iPhone for work, it may well be work-related.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Yes, if you let an employee provide personal services to you, you are probably committing tax fraud, because the cost of the employee is tax-deductible as a cost of business, while if you paid it out of your own pocket, it would not be tax-deductible. Whether it really is fraud, and whether it will be prosecuted depends on lots of factors (plus in this case it's rather a minor thing).

Comment: She is the sole owner. I don't know why exactly, but she doesn't seem to trust the advice or expertise of "outsiders" such as people at the phone store (who probably get paid more than I do).